# Angular 6.0 firebase hosting deploy not working

Tags: angular, firebase-hosting, firebase-tools

I am looking for a tutorial on how to properly setup the `firebase-tools` hosting on my angular 6.0 projects, and what I found is always like this.

```
- firebase init 
- then select the Hosting
- What do you want to use as your public directory? dist
- Configure as a single-page app (rewrite all urls to /index.html)? Yes
- Overwrite? No
- ng build --prod
- firebase deploy
```

but after doing this, this is always what I've got.

[image: default]

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I found that the `ng build --prod` will create a `dist` and an another subfolder under this where the project location is.

```
dist
|--TheProject_Folder
|  |--assets|index.html - This index html is not using.
|--index.html - This is the html generated in the firebase init
```

So what I did is to initialize again the `firebase init`
and change the **public directory** from `dist` to `dist/TheProject_Folder`:

```
- What do you want to use as your public directory? dist/TheProject_Folder
- Configure as a single-page app (rewrite all urls to /index.html)? Yes
- Overwrite? No
```

Comment: Angular v6 CLI projects are making it easier to have multiple apps with shared codebases. Hence the new folder within `dist`. I recently launched a new [guide for Angular on Firebase](https://pwa.ng/) you might find interesting.

Comment: or.. just edit firebase.json, change "public: dist" to "public: dist/your_project_folder"

Comment: It works for me. It took effect after a couple of minutes I deployed

Comment: Overwrite? N    fixed the problem

Comment: changing the public directory from dist to dist/TheProject_Folder did the trick. Thanks a ton !!

Comment: so basically, firebase added another index.html under dist which is not created by `ng build --prod` and under firebase.json we have to specify the index.html inside the `dist/your-project-name` - I hope Firebase documentation says this in its future documentation revisions.

Comment: Thanks so much! Now I know that I needed to point to the dist folder. Legend

Answer (score 21):

Below is step by step process to host angular6.0 app on firebase

1] `npm install -g firebase-tool`  Install firebase tool

2] `firebase login` Use the CLI tools to login in Firebase.

After connecting to our account/Gmail-account, we will get the **firebase CLI Login Successfull** message in browser

3] `firebase init`

*Here are the answers to the questions Firebase tools will ask:*

> ? Are you ready to proceed? **Yes**
>   ? Which Firebase CLI features do you
>   want to setup for this folder? Press Space to select features, then
>   Enter to confirm your choices. **Hosting: Configure and deploy Firebase
>   Hosting sites**
>
> ? What do you want to use as your public directory? **dist** `(This is important! Angular creates the dist folder.)`
>
> ? Configure as a single-page app (rewrite all urls to /index.
>   html)? **Yes**

4] `ng build --prod`

> This will create a brand new dist/ folder in our project with the
>   files necessary to launch our app.

5] Before deploying the app, go to firebase.json file and specify your project public field like this

```
"public": "dist/your_project_name",
```

6] Now deploy the project in firebase using below command

> firebase deploy

After depolying you will get the below message

> - Deploy complete!
>
> Project Console: https://************ [you will get the actual url
>   name rather than stars]
>
> Hosting URL: https://*************  [you will get the actual url name
>   rather than stars]
>
> you can access the website by the URL given in Hosting URL

Comment: Editing firebase.json to update public folder was key, it worked like charm. Thanks :)

Answer (score 9):

it worked me after i remove cache and refresh browser, thanks.

Comment: **Thanks man.**
I tired from deploying and trying until have read your comment and **clear the cache**.

Comment: I can't believe how many times I deployed fruitlessly, trying to get this to work.  Thanks user698314!

Comment: helped me out hugely!!

Comment: THIS WORKED! I really cant thank you enough!

Answer (score 4):

The second possible way is just to change outputPath in angular.json to dist, so the line will look like this `"outputhPath": "dist"`

Comment: This fixed it for me. Before it was creating a new folder in the dist that contained all the built files as well.

Answer (score 1):

It worked when I cleared the cache with `ctrl+shift+R` hard reset on the web! Make sure the correct `index.html` file is being deployed on firebase.

Answer (score 0):

@bajran may have elborated all steps in detail but if you are migrating from angular 5 to 6, the only step that matters is,
changing  `"public": "dist",` to `"public": "dist/your_project_name",` in firebase.json

Answer (score 0):

There's one more issue that can lead to this very same page. 
When we init the project by using the

`firebase init`

command and following the procedure, it by default overwrites the index.html file.
So, if already built(to get the dist/_Project_Folder) the index.html file is overwritten.
Built it again after

```
firebase init 
ng build --prod
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that on the question

> File dist/apps/ditectrev/index.html already exists. Overwrite?

If you'll type **Y for Yes**, then it'll create its own index.html file, generated by Firebase. Giving this **N for No** I was able to keep my original **index.html**, which was generated after using `ng build --prod` in `dist/apps/ditectrev`. Note: I'm using Nx workspace, but the same should apply for other Angular projects. In normal Angular project case it would be different path, which would be simply `dist`.

Answer (score 0):

If u don`t have a single page app (like me), when Firebase ask

```
File dist/apps/ditectrev/index.html already exists. Overwrite?
```

Write N. I have tried so many times before figure out

Answer (score 0):

You can check if there is a firebase.json and .firebaserc files created. If not, this solution is for you.

**Step 1**: After you firebase deploy and its not working, you can create the firebase.json file and paste this code :

```
{ "database": {
"rules": "firebase_rules.json"},
"hosting": {
"public": "dist/"yourdistfilename",
"ignore": [
  "firebase.json",
  "**/.*",
  "**/node_modules/**"
  ]  
 }
}
```

**Step 2** : Create firebase_rules.json and paste this code:

```
{  "rules": {
    ".read": false,
    ".write": false
 }
}
```

Note that you name the file firebase.json and firebase_rules.json

**Step 3**: in terminal run this firebase init database. This question will appear and follow the answer.

1. What file should be used for Realtime Database Security Rules? ***firebase_rules.json***
2. File firebase_rules.json already exists. Do you want to overwrite it with the Realtime Database Security Rules (y/N) ***y*** (to overwrite and update to latest code)

**Step 4**: Then you notice that .firebaserc have been created.

**Step 5**: You need to run firebase init and firebase deploy one more time. Now you can finally see your project!

It's not much but hope this can help.